Typing a function param to be any JSON serializable object
what would be the best type for this function?
I want basically any input type that json.dumps can process (with or without JSONEncoder)
For now i'm using Union[List[Any], Dict[Any, Any]] but it's not exhaustive and mypy complains Explicit "Any" is not allowed
import json
from typing import List, Dict
from datetime import date


def my_function_doing_stuff_then_serializing(input: Union[List[Any], Dict[Any, Any]], **kwargs) -> None:
    json.dumps(input, **kwargs)


so I can do this
import json
from datetime import date
from somewhere import my_function_doing_stuff_then_serializing


class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(obj, date):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return super().default(obj)

my_function_doing_stuff_then_serializing([date.today()], cls=DateEncoder)



Does this answer your question? Define a jsonable type using mypy / PEP-526

If you have a newer python version you should be able to use a recursive TypeAlias: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182#issuecomment-1320974824

oh, and you need a current mypy

indeed I have the current mypy so JsonType = Union[None, int, str, bool, List[JsonType], Dict[str, JsonType]] works perfectly.

still not sure how things work here, @srn you can go ahead and create an answer, or should I?

Using a current version of mypy, you can now use recursive a TypeAlias, which is a "special marker indicating that an assignment should be recognized as a proper type alias definition by type checkers".
In your case, you could do either:
from typing import List, Dict, Union
JsonType = Union[None, int, str, bool, List[JsonType], Dict[str, JsonType]]

or, using the TypeAlias marker for checkers:
from typing import List, Dict, Union, TypeAlias
JsonType: TypeAlias = Union[None, int, str, bool, List[JsonType], Dict[str, JsonType]]

And as mentioned in this discussion, there are many more ways to define such aliases according to your specific needs.
